# Fetching only in the second click

Tags: javascript, frontend, fetch-api

I have a problem on my fetching.
I fetched API to my project, when I trying to use display on value, it doesn't work on the first click. at the second click the function will run good and everything works.

When I'm trying to log in the fetching function everything works good, but, at the display function I get an error:

Also if I write a number of Pokemon to search and click to search it doesn't work but, if I change it and click again, I will get the first Pokemon value.

> **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'name')**

I'm adding the function of the fetch and also the display function.
I can also send the git repository if anyone want to help.

```
let fetetchPokemon = function (inputNum) {
      fetch(`${pokemonApi}` + `${inputNum}`)
        .then((response) => response.json())
    
        // .then((response) => console.log(response))
        .then(
          (response) =>
            (pokemon = new Pokemon(
              response.name,
              response.sprites,
              response.moves,
              response.types,
              response.abilities
            ))
        )
        // .then((pokemon) => console.log(pokemon.name));
        // .then((pokemon) => console.log(pokemon.name))
        .then(displayPokemon());
    };
   
    let displayPokemon = function () {
      pokemonName.innerText = pokemon.name;
      console.log(pokemon.name);
      pokemonImg.src = pokemon.image.front_default;
      displayMoves(pokemon.moves);
      displayType(pokemon.types);
      displayAbilities(pokemon.abilities);
    };
```

There is also a bin to see the code:
https://jsbin.com/puvotid/edit?html,css,js,output

Comment: This code snippet you shared does not tell the scenario properly. Could you please share more details code snippet or give me any link JS bin /something?

Comment: It may cause due to global `pokemon` is not an object. Second time the name can be shown is data from previous action. Update your post with more detail @Doron

Comment: i added a bin of the code

Comment: @DoronDavid Move & replace `.then(displayPokemon());` by `displayPokemon()` to after `pokemon` variable assignment into closure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The display method must be placed same scope with variable assignment.
So the method will look like

```
const fetetchPokemon = function (inputNum) {
  fetch(`${pokemonApi}` + `${inputNum}`)
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then(
      (response) => {
        pokemon = new Pokemon(
          response.name,
          response.sprites,
          response.moves,
          response.types,
          response.abilities
        );
        
        displayPokemon();
      }
    );
};
```

As answer below from @Mamoud, you should use async/await or callback invidually, not both

Answer (score 0):

use `async` and `await` to wait the results.

```js
const fetchPokemon = async function(){
    await fetch(...).then(...)
}
```

Comment: it still send me the same Error and work only at the second time.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).